# SQLite or JDBC strange behaviour

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite

I have a simple version table in databse. Here is DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE version (current STRING NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO version (current) VALUES ("1.0");
```

In this table stored only one row with current database structure version. At the first blush everything is good, but here is a little strange thing:

```
//... connect to SQLite and another stuff...
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select current from version;");
if(!resultSet.next())
    throw new SQLException("Corrupted version table! Aborting...");
String versionStr = resultSet.getString(1);
System.out.println("Version string: '" + versionStr + "'");
//... close statement, blah-blah-blah
```

Output is: '1'. Where is '.0' missed? If current value is '0.1', '1.3' and fraction part is not zero - everything is good. Since it zero - '.0' is lost.

So, question is: why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STRING` isn't a SQLite data type, so the column `current` defaults to the `NUMERIC` affinity and tries to convert whatever has been inserted into it into a number. Change `STRING` to `TEXT` and the column will keep your data as a string.

The [Datatypes in SQLite3](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) documentation page gives a more in-depth explanation:

> The affinity of a column is determined by the declared type of the
>   column, according to the following rules in the order shown:
>
> If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned
>   INTEGER affinity.
>
> If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR",
>   "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the
>   type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT
>   affinity.
>
> If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no
>   type is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.
>
> If the declared type for a column contains any of the strings "REAL",
>   "FLOA", or "DOUB" then the column has REAL affinity.
>
> Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC.

Comment: "Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC.", yeap. Thank you, I missed it up.